# create a new column by grouping values from an existing column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, split

I have the following dataframe:

```
  Date       power                
1 16/12/2006 4.216              
2 17/12/2006 5.360              
3 18/12/2006 5.374              
4 19/12/2006 5.388                 
5 20/12/2006 3.666                 
6 21/12/2006 3.520
```

I would like to create a new column to group the values of power into intervals say 0-0.5, 0.5-1 and so on upto 5.5-6. I'm fairly new to R. I think it is possible using split function but not sure how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to create your bins.

```
# Create break from  0 to 10 in 0.5 intervals
breaks = seq(0, 10, 0.5)

# Create bin column
data$bins = cut(data$power, breaks)
```

You can keep the value of data$bins as intervals,
or convert (coerce) to numeric by

```
 data$bins = as.numeric(data$bins).
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The data$bins = cut(data$power, breaks) gave an error saying that x should be numeric. It turns out that power belongs to factor class. I tried to make it numeric by using as.numeric(data$power) but the result has some missing and nonsensical values in the bins column.

Comment: If you coerce factor to numeric, it will convert to factor level, not the character field, which happens to be numeric. One way to get around this is to convert to character and then to numeric. as.numeric(as.character(data$power)) will do the job.