# Grouping ranges of values in a new column Rstudio

Tags: r

I would like to group a range values in a new column. I already saw multiple examples like:
[create a new column by grouping values from an existing column of a dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205555/create-a-new-column-by-grouping-values-from-an-existing-column-of-a-dataframe-in), and others. But, I would like to get something like these:

```
x -> [1 2 3 4 5: 1 2 3 4 5] 

gr-> [1 1 1 1 1: 2 2 2 2 2]
```

I have 3751 raws that repeat from 0 to 120, i.e., 31 repetitions. So I would like that the first 120 raws are = 1, the second 0:1:120 raws are = 2 and so on.

I tried this but didn't work

```
breaks = seq(0, 3751, 121)
data_sp$bins = cut(data_sp$hour.inc, breaks)
data_sp$bins = as.numeric(data_sp$bins)
```

Comment: `gr <- rep(1:31, each=120)` but that only gives you 3720 values not 3751. Perhaps you meant 121?

Comment: Thank dcarlson! Yes, it is 121 because is from 0 to 120. I already did with your example and it worked.